# Only Encrypted image should save in file and decrypting image for preview

Tags: java, android, image, encryption

In This code file is saving original image, Encrypted image and decrypted Image.

I have two problems in that :

1. Only Encrypted image should store in the file(savedimages)
2. The Encrypted image should be decrypted directly to bytearray or Something which can be set as bitmap in imageView. Currently its taking from file directly.

Is there any way to achieve this or I should try some others methods

```
public Main3Activity() {
    try {
      //  SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG","Crypto");

        keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Blowfish");
        secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);


    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, CAMERA, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    v1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewnew);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cameranew);

    final String imagePath = "image" + ".png";
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "savedimages");
    root.mkdirs();
    if (!root.exists()) {
        root.mkdir();
    }

    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "savedimages",imagePath);
    file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "savedimages","Encryp"+imagePath);
    file2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "savedimages","decryp"+imagePath);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

        }
    });
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


        OutputStream outStream = null;
        InputStream inStream = null;
        try {

            System.out.println("Encryption Over");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            inStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(file1);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;

            while ((len = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outStream.write(cipher.update(buffer, 0, len));
                outStream.flush();
            }
            outStream.write(cipher.doFinal());
            outStream.close();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }


        try {
            System.out.println("Decryption Over");

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            inStream = new FileInputStream(file1);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(file2);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;

            while ((len = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
            //------------>>>>>>>>>    Here Image is Storing instead of that it should read as byte array
                // ------------>>>>>>>>>>   and read as bitmap and set in Imageview for preview

                outStream.write(cipher.update(buffer, 0, len));
                outStream.flush();
            }
            System.out.print("Decryption ovverrr");
            outStream.write(cipher.doFinal());
            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }


        BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        final Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file2.toString(),options);
        System.out.println("Image getting from File");

        //----------->>>>>>>>>> Decrypted Image should view Here. Currently I am getting directly from file.
        v1.setImageBitmap(b);

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-storage) Library I have found out the solution for my question. This could be helpful to someone.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    v1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewnew);
    v2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewupdate);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cameranew);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cameraupp);


    String IVX = "abcdefghijklmnop"; // 16 lenght - not secret
    String SECRET_KEY = "secret1234567890"; // 16 lenght - secret

    SimpleStorageConfiguration configuration = new SimpleStorageConfiguration.Builder()
            .setEncryptContent(IVX, SECRET_KEY)
            .build();

    if (SimpleStorage.isExternalStorageWritable()) {
        storage = SimpleStorage.getExternalStorage();
    }
    else {
        storage = SimpleStorage.getInternalStorage(getApplicationContext());
    }

    SimpleStorage.updateConfiguration(configuration);

    imagePath = "image" + ".png";
    boolean dirExists = storage.isDirectoryExists("savedimages");

    if(dirExists==true)
    {
        System.out.println("Directoy Already Created");
    }
    else {
        storage.createDirectory("savedimages", true);
    }

    boolean fileExists = storage.isFileExist("savedimages",imagePath);

    if(fileExists==true) {
        System.out.println("File Already Created");
    }
    else {
        storage.createFile("savedimages", imagePath, " ");
    }

    ff=storage.getFile("savedimages",imagePath);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(ff);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

        }
    });
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        final Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ff.toString(),options);
        v2.setImageBitmap(b);

        storage.createFile("savedimages",imagePath,b);

    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This [library](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-storage) provides encryption at some point, but I didn't check what kind of encryption maybe it'll be enough for you. It's easier to use then Java File class.

Comment: Yes bro, Its perfectly working.  It took me a whole day to understand.  Yet some common Errors like Out of memory Error,  Failed to read Stream like that happening after finishing i will update my Answer.  Is there any others library available like this